# How to arrange data values into arrays based on their key - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I've got some data from my model (in a variable called `results`) and I'd like to organise it into arrays based on their key. I.E, each genreName value should be pushed into the genres[] array, each actorID into the cast[] array.

`results`:

```
#<Genre genreName: "Fantasy">
#<Genre genreName: "Comedy">
#<Genre genreName: "Children">
#<Genre genreName: "Animation">
#<Genre genreName: "Adventure">
#<Actor actorID: "tom_hanks", actorName: "Tom Hanks">
#<Actor actorID: "tim_allen", actorName: "Tim Allen">
#<Actor actorID: "don_rickles", actorName: "Don Rickles">
#<Actor actorID: "jim_varney", actorName: "Jim Varney">
#<Actor actorID: "wallace_shawn", actorName: "Wallace Shawn">
#<Director directorID: "john_lasseter", directorName: "John Lasseter">
#<Country countryName: "USA">
#<Location locationName: "N/A">
```

What would you suggest? I'm trying to complete this in Ruby.

**EDIT**

Maybe it would make more sense to add all object values to a Hash, but I'm worried about unique key names...

Comment: You should show `results` as a valid Ruby object. Assuming it's an array of strings: `results = ["#<Genre genreName: "Fantasy">, ..."#<Location locationName: "N/A">"]`.

Comment: ...and if `results` is an array of class instances, that needs to be said.

Answer (score 0):

```
genre_names = results.map { |object| object.genreName if object.class.name == "Genre" }
```

This will iterate through each object in results and return an array with each of the genreName fields by only including the objects of class "Genre". You can then do something similar with the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

(Edit: I may have misunderstood the question. I took the data to be an array of strings, but it seems more likely that they are class instances.)

```
results = <<_.lines
#<Genre genreName: "Fantasy">
#<Genre genreName: "Comedy">
#<Genre genreName: "Children">
#<Genre genreName: "Animation">
#<Genre genreName: "Adventure">
#<Actor actorID: "tom_hanks", actorName: "Tom Hanks">
#<Actor actorID: "tim_allen", actorName: "Tim Allen">
#<Actor actorID: "don_rickles", actorName: "Don Rickles">
#<Actor actorID: "jim_varney", actorName: "Jim Varney">
#<Actor actorID: "wallace_shawn", actorName: "Wallace Shawn">
#<Director directorID: "john_lasseter", directorName: "John Lasseter">
#<Country countryName: "USA">
#<Location locationName: "N/A">
_
```

You could do this:

```
R = /
    \b        # Match a word break
    (genreName|actorID|cast) # Match one of three strings in capture group 1
    \b        # Match a word break 
    (?=       # Begin a positive lookahead 
      :\s+\"  # Match : >= 1 whitespace double quote
      (\w+)   # Match >= 1 word characters in capture group 2
      \"      # Match double quote
    )         # End postive lookahead
    /x        # Extended/free-spacing regex definition mode


h = results.each_with_object({ genreName: [], actorID: [], cast: [] }) { |s,h|
  s.scan(R) { h[$1.to_sym] << $2 } }
  #=> {:genreName=>["Fantasy", "Comedy", "Children", "Animation", "Adventure"],
  #    :actorID=>["tom_hanks", "tim_allen", "don_rickles", "jim_varney", "wallace_shawn"],
  #    :cast=>[]}
```

Then

```
actorID = h[:actorID]
```

and so on.